eslint for "empty" statements
I accidentally wrote some pretty crappy code.
My intention was to write this
let a = 0;
...
a = 2;

But instead of assigning to a, I accidentally got a double =
let a = 0;
...
a == 2;

I know that it is valid javascript and typescript, but I feel like there has to be some lint checks that blocks this sort of thing from happening, because I cannot for the life of me see any point in writing such code.
So is there an eslint rule I can use that checks for these types of noop/empty statements?

For JavaScript, you can use no-unused-expressions.
For TypeScript, you can use @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions.
Also check out this demos in ESLint playground and TypeScript ESLint playground.
